# How is solving Proca equation equivalent to scalar field equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, mass, field-theory

My prof. told me that using differential forms proca equation reduces to solving for scalar field equation. How is that? I can’t see how does one relate to Scalar equation using differential forms.

Proca equation: $$\mathcal{L} = \frac{-1}{16}F^{\mu v}F_{\mu v} + \frac{1}{8\pi}m^2A_\mu A^\mu.$$

Equation of motion for Proca: $$\partial_\mu F^{\mu v} + m^2 A^v = 0.$$

Comment: You do not need differential forms to match Proca Equation to 4 independent Klein-Gordon Equations

Comment: How is it done then ? Also how are differential forms used in field theory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian that you use for the Proca equation looks a bit unusual, I will factor out $\frac{1}{8}$ and change the factor  ($\frac{m}{\sqrt{\pi}} \rightarrow \frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}$): Then written out in differential forms it looks like:

$$L = 8{\cal{L}} =-\frac{1}{2} dA \wedge \star dA + \frac{1}{2} m^2   A\wedge \star A$$

We will derive the L-E equations via variation (actually I did most of it already in another post, so I will shorten the derivation a little bit, the details can be looked up in the post https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/432941/30506 ):

$$\delta S =\int\delta L = -\frac{1}{2} \int (d\delta A \wedge \star dA + dA \wedge \star d\delta A) +  \frac{1}{2} m^2  \int (\delta A \wedge \star A + A\wedge \star \delta A) =   -\frac{1}{2} \int 2 d\delta A \wedge \star dA + m^2 \int \delta A \wedge \star A $$

In the next manipulation we will use the product rule:

$$d(\delta A\wedge \star d A) = d\delta A \wedge\star dA - \delta A \wedge d\star dA $$ therefore we have:  $$-d\delta A\wedge \star dA = - d(\delta A\wedge \star dA ) -\delta A\wedge d\star dA $$.

We will this substitute in the first term of the varied action:

$$\delta S =\int  - d(\delta A\wedge \star dA )  -\int  \delta A\wedge d\star dA  + m^2  \int \delta A \wedge \star A $$

Finally the first term is an integral over an absolute derivative which be transformed into a surface integral on whose surface the variation $\delta A=0$.   So we get finally:

$$0=\delta S  = - \int \delta A \wedge  (d\star dA  - m^2  \star A )$$

As the last expression has to be zero for all variations  $\delta A$, the result of the variation is:

$$d\star dA  - m^2   \star A =0 $$  or a bit more nicely written (actually at the moment I don't know if $\star \star =1$ or $\star \star =-1$, but I will check that up).

$$ \star d\star dA = m^2 A$$

In some books $ \delta: =  \star d\star$ (this $\delta$, however, has nothing to do with the variation) and with $F=dA$ we get:

$$\delta F =m^2 A $$

The definition of the hodge operator can be looked up in the other post  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/432941/30506  I mentioned at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

They reduce to 4 Klein-Gordon equation Because, as noted in a comment by the OP, the 4-divergence of $A^\nu$ is identically 0, this follow directly from the equation of motion. So we have

$$
\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Now, we start from the equation of motion you propose

$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} + m^2 A^\nu = 0  
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}
$$

We insert the definition of the tensor $F^{\mu\nu} = \partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu $ and we obtain

$$
\partial_\mu (\partial^\mu A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu) + m^2 A^\nu  = 0 \tag{3} 
$$

From there we get

$$
\partial^\mu \partial_\mu A^\nu - \partial_\mu \partial^\nu  A^\mu + m^2A^\nu = \Box A^\nu -  \partial^\nu \partial_\mu  A^\mu + m^2A^\nu = 0 \tag{4}
$$

Where in the first equality in equation $(4)$, in the second term, I just swapped the derivatives $\partial_\mu$ with $\partial^\nu$

Now if we use $(1)$ in $(4)$ the second term vanishes and we obtain

$$
(\Box + m^2)A^\nu  = 0 \tag{5}
$$

Which is just a set of 4 Klein-Gordon equations, one for each component of the $4-$vector $A^\nu$. 
Notice that those are not $4$ equation for $4$ scalar fields, but for the components of a $4-$ vector.

Comment: You don’t need lorentz guage I guess because $F^{uv}$ is a anti symmetric tensor when acted by $\partial_u$ in right hand side first term ( involving F disappers ) and then we get lorentz guage

Comment: You don't get a gauge, you Impose one. $F$ is antysimmetrical for exchange of $\mu$ and $\nu$, it doesn't disappear if you derive it by $\partial_\mu$, it will if you derive it by it by $\partial_\mu \partial_\nu$

Comment: you get the following as equation as motion : $\partial_a F^{ab} + m^2 A^b = 0$. Note that $\partial_b \partial_a F^{ab} = 0$. Hence $\partial_b(\partial_a F^{ab} + m^2 A^b )= 0$, which implies $\partial_b A^b = 0 $. This is only true because mass is not zero.

Comment: You are right, there's no need to impose the Lorenz gauge, it's a consequence of the equation of motion. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated, hope it's clearer now