# Can the Lagrangian density of vacuum Maxwell equation be written into tensor contraction without a basis?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations

The Lagrangian density of the Maxwell equations in vacuum is
$$
\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} . \tag{1}
$$

My question is, $F$ is a [tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Using_tensor_products), namely
$$
F = \frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu} dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{\nu}. \tag{2}
$$
Thus, does Eq.(1) specify to the component $F_{\mu\nu}$, rather than the whole tensor (including basis)?

But, Eq. (1) looks like a [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction), which can be defined in the whole tensor without specify to a basis. E.g.,
$$C: V \otimes V^* \rightarrow k$$
as in the wikipedia link.
To this end, is that possible to rewrite the action (1) into abstract contraction (without basis) form, something like $ F \otimes F^* \rightarrow$?

Comment: $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is sometimes written $F^2$.

Comment: @Ghoster Yes.. Then, to some extent, that answered my question, if $F^2$ means a tensor contraction without referring to a basis

Comment: There is also [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation), Penrose’s way to notate contractions without using a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all one should consider that the electromagnetic (EM) field tensor is antisymmetric and is written in differential form as the exterior derivative of the 1-form $A$ (also known as 4-potential):

$$F = d\wedge A \equiv dA$$

In this formalism the action $S$ of the EM-field can be written as:

$$S=-\frac{1}{2} \int F \wedge \star F$$

where $\star$ is the hodge operator which maps a p-form $\omega$ into a $n-p$ form (where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold)

$$ \star: \quad \omega \in \Lambda_p(M)  \longrightarrow  \star\omega \in \Lambda_{n-p}(M)$$

where $M$ is the manifold where $\omega$ and $\star\omega$ live.
In components it is defined as: If

$$\omega = \frac{1}{p!}\omega_{i_1,\ldots,i_p} dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots \wedge dx^{i_p}$$

then $\star\omega$ is ($g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor that is equal to $-1$ in case of a Minkowski metric):

$$\star\omega = \frac{1}{p!} \sqrt{|g|} \epsilon_{i_1,\ldots,i_n} \omega^{i_1,\ldots,i_p} dx^{i_{p+1}}\wedge\ldots \wedge dx^{i_n}$$

$\epsilon_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$ is the alternating permutation symbol which is completely antisymmetric. $e_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}:= \sqrt{|g|} \epsilon_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$ is called the Levi-Civita tensor.

The hodge operator is very useful, in particular when it comes to writing integrals in a coordinate-independent form. On 4-dimensional space changes 0-forms into 4-forms in the following way:

$$\star 1 = -cdt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz \quad \text{and the other way around}\quad \star (cdt \wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz) = 1$$

In particular on 2-forms like the EM-field tensor the different contributions to it can be transformed with $\star$ as:

$$\star (cdt \wedge dx) = dy \wedge dz$$
$$\star (cdt \wedge dy) =-dx \wedge dz$$
$$\star (cdt \wedge dz) = dx \wedge dy$$
$$\star (dx  \wedge dy) =-cdt \wedge dz$$
$$\star (dx  \wedge dz) = cdt \wedge dy$$
$$\star (dy \wedge  dz) =-cdt \wedge dx$$

I quoted for the last identities of the $\star$-operator the book of Shlomo Sternberg on "Curvature in Mathematics and Physics"(Dover publications)  whereas in the first part I quoted Norbert Straumann's book on General Relativity and relativistic astrophysics" (Springer). It is possible that both books use different conventions on the definitions of the $\star$-operator.

BTW, the desired expression for a coordinate free expression of the Lagrangian for the EM-field is a 4-form, which corresponds well to a scalar Lagrange density times $d^4x$.

More on the use of the $\star$-operator can be found in my post [Maxwell equations of motion from $S = \frac{-1}{2} \int F \wedge \ast F$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432905/maxwell-equations-of-motion-from-s-frac-12-int-f-wedge-ast-f/432941#432941)

Comment: Thank you very much! The BTW clarifies a lot to me. I thought $F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$ led to a scalar, but $\wedge *$ led to a 4-form. Nevertheless, the full expression is $S = \int \mathcal{L} d^4 x$, where the 4-form is the integral element

Comment: And in the second equation of this answer, is the $F \wedge * F$ or $dA \wedge * dA$, than $dF \wedge * dF$?

Comment: @RandomUser $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ *is* a scalar. As is $S$.

Comment: @RandomUser Ooh!! The $d$ on the $F$ has been an oversight of myself. I am sorry. I corrected it.

Comment: Differential forms are constructed in a way that in all expressions which are an integrand $\times$ differential the differential is already part of the differential form.

Comment: I’ve never seen $d\wedge A$ for $dA$, and it doesn’t make sense to me since $d$ is not itself a differential form. Have you seen this notation somewhere?

Comment: @Ghoster yes, it is for instance used in the book of Sexl & Urbantke on "Gravitation and Cosmology". I put it at the beginning to make clear that $d$ is the exterior derivative.

Answer (score 2):

With the two-form $F= \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu} \, dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu$, the action integral of the (free) electromagnetic field can be written as $S=-\frac{1}{2} \int F \wedge \ast F$. Note that the dynamical field in the action integral is the one-form $A= A_\mu dx^\mu$ with $F=dA$. (See e.g. W. Thirring, Classical Mathematical Physics for details.)